# Merge 2 lists containing obejcts with matching ids

Tags: python

I have 2 lists that contain objects that look like this:

list 1:

```
{'name': 'Nick', 'id': '123456'}
```

list 2:

```
{'address': 'London', 'id': '123456'}
```

Now I want to create a third list, containing objects that look like this:

```
{'name': 'Nick', 'address': 'London', 'id': '123456'}
```

i.e, I want to find the matching id's, and merge those objects.

Comment: Do you have any duplicate `id`s in the same list?  If so you need to define your collision policy (take the first?  take the last?  throw an error?)  Also, is `set(x['id'] for x in list1) == set(x['id'] for x in list2)`?

Comment: @0x5453 no duplicates :) will at most be 2 of the same id.

Comment: Those are dicts, not objects. You're coming from Javascript, eh? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get all the matching dicts, then unify them using [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), like this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import ChainMap

list1 = [{'name': 'Nick', 'id': '123456'}, {'name': 'Donald', 'id': '999'}]
list2 = [{'address': 'London', 'id': '123456'}, {'address': 'NYC', 'id': '999'}]

grouped_subdicts = groupby(sorted(list1 + list2, key=itemgetter("id")), itemgetter("id"))

result = [dict(ChainMap(*g)) for k, g in grouped_subdicts]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '123456', 'address': 'London', 'name': 'Nick'},
{'id': '999', 'address': 'NYC', 'name': 'Donald'}]
```

Comment: This is nice.  Also instead of writing a `for` loop over the `grouped_subdicts` and using `update`, you could comprehend over `grouped_subdicts` and apply `dict(ChainMap(g))` to each group.

Comment: @KyleParsons awesome!! I hate `for` loops :P thanks!